# How do I resend pings every five minutes to my list of IP Addresses

Tags: c#, ip-address, ping

First forgive me, I am very new to C#, I am trying to teach myself the language at the same time as creating this program.

I have a list of IP Addresses, buttons for each of those Ip addresses are being created on a tablelayoutpanel inside a flowlayoutpanel.  The Tag for each of those buttons is the IP address for the button.

Right now the code below pings once to the ip address and turns the buttons from control grey to either red or green based off how the ping returned.

```
private void tlp_ControlAdded(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
{
    IPAddress ip;
    if(IPAddress.TryParse((string)e.Control.Tag,out ip))
    {
        Ping pingIt = new Ping();
        pingIt.PingCompleted += pingIt_PingCompleted;
        pingIt.SendAsync(ip, 2000, e.Control);
    }
}

void pingIt_PingCompleted(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Control ctrl = (Control)e.UserState;
    if (e.Reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
    {
        ctrl.BackColor = Color.Lime;
    }
    else
    {
        ctrl.BackColor = Color.Red;
        ctrl.ForeColor = Color.White;
    }
}
```

What I would like the program to do is to re-ping those ip addresses every five minutes until the form is closed and color the buttons respectably if any change in the ping response occurs.

EDIT::::
So what you are suggesting is something like this?  Only I am getting 4 erros from the code.

1.The best overloaded method match for 'SCA_Up_Tool.Form2.TimerTick(object, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)' has some invalid arguments
2.Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.ControlEventArgs' to 'System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs'
3.System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'Control' and no extension method 'Control' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
4.'System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'Control' and no extension method 'Control' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
System.Timers.Timer pingTimer;

private void tlp_ControlAdded(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
{
    PingTimerStart(sender, e);
}

void PingTimerStart(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
{
    pingTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(300000); // 300 seconds - 5 minutes
    pingTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(TimerTick(sender, e));
    pingTimer.Start();
}

void TimerTick(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    IPAddress ip;
    if (IPAddress.TryParse((string)e.Control.Tag, out ip))
    {
        Ping pingIt = new Ping();
        pingIt.PingCompleted += pingIt_PingCompleted;
        pingIt.SendAsync(ip, 2000, e.Control);
    }
}

void pingIt_PingCompleted(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Control ctrl = (Control)e.UserState;
    if (e.Reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
    {
        ctrl.BackColor = Color.Lime;
    }
    else
    {
        ctrl.BackColor = Color.Red;
        ctrl.ForeColor = Color.White;
    }
}
```

Comment: use a timer - thats what they are there for!

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods, but the simplest solution would be to use a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx).

Try something like

```
Timer pingTimer;
void PingTimerStart()
{
  pingTimer = new Timer(300000); // 300 seconds - 5 minutes
  pingTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
  pingTimer.Start();
}

void TimerTick(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
  // Send ping code here
}
```